# Logic of for loop in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

> ```
> ****
> ***
> **
> *
> ```

```
/*code for this pattern*/

#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{ 
  int i, j;
  for (i = 4 ; i >= 1 ; --i) {
    for (j = 1 ; j <= i; ++j) { /*why does j<=i?*/
         printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

So why does `j <= i`? the first for loop is responsible for the rows. While the second for loop in responsible for the number of stars in each row. again, `i` don't understand the logic of the condition- `j <= i`.
EDIT: C is the first language I have ever tried to really learn. The question is pretty clear, i think. I don't understand the condition component of the for loop. Thats all. Some people understood what I was asking though. thanks

EDIT2: seems like i wasn't clear with my question. I want to to know why does j has to be less or equal to i. why can i be less or equal than j? I am having trouble seeing the relationship between i, the number of rows and j, the number of stars in each row.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are you trying to do ? Learn C ? Or solve a real problem ?

Comment: Use a debugger, or a pencil and paper, and see what's happening.

Comment: What do you mean, "why does j <= i"?

Comment: What in particular don't you understand? I am glad you have a very short example but I don't know what to say other than "that is one of the ways to make a loop that runs `i` times"

Comment: In the first `i` loop, `i==4` so the `j` loop will print 4 stars. In the second `i` loop, `i==3` so the `j` loop will print 3 stars, and so on.

Comment: did you even step this into a debugger to grasp the mechanics of the code. That is a basic 101 thing to do..?

Comment: Why don't you go through it giving values to `i` and `j` on a paper and try to understand, asking people about this is not going to allow you to unveil the mistery loosing a valuable portion of your lesson.

Comment: Is google down? http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.5.3

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the outer for loop is for the number of rows. The inner for loop is to print the `*` n times, where n is the number of times the character has to be printed in that row.

i.e) In the first iteration : i = 4, so, j = 1;j<=4 executes 4 times so you print 4 `*`.

In the second iteration : i = 3, so j = 1;j<=3 executes thrice, so you print 3 `*`

Answer (score 0):

i starts high and decrements while i is >= 1. j starts low at 1, and increments while j is <= i.

This means that while i is a greater value, j will be incremented more times, which means we want to start off with printing a greater amount of '*'s from the start, and after each newline character, slowly narrow that strand of '*'s.

The inner loop is essentially there to execute that printf() call exactly i times. So you end up with 4 '*'s for the first iteration, 3 for the next, 2, then 1. Each on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

The number of stars on each row, and the number of rows remaining to print (including the current row) are both equal to `i`. So `i` is being used both to countdown the number of rows left to print, and also as the number of stars to print on each row. On the first row `i == 4`, so you want to print four stars, so you have a loop:

```
for(j = 1; j<=4; ++j) {
     printf("*")
}
```

next time `i` will be 3, so the inner loop will be:

```
for(j = 1; j<=3; ++j) {
     printf("*")
}
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

> ```
> for(j = 1; j<=i; ++j){ /*why does j<=i?*/
> ```

When `i` is equal to `4`, you want to print four `*`s.
When `i` is equal to `3`, you want to print three `*`s.

The check `j <= i` makes sure of that.

Answer (score 0):

For each loop, you should think about how many times it is iterated.
As you said, in the first for loop,

```
for(i = 4; i >=1; --i){ ...
```

This for loop iterates while `i >= 1`, meaning `i` changes to `4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1` (i.e. 4 times = number of rows).

For each row, you want to print `i` number of `*`'s, which means you want to repeat the printing process `i` times for each row. In the nested loop,

```
for(j = 1; j <= i; ++j){ ...
```

`j` iterates while `j <= i`, meaning `1 -> 2 -> ... -> i` (i.e. `i` times for each row). It is by the way practically the same as

```
for(j = 0; j < i; ++j) {...
```

which iterates `i` times as well.